# How to instantiate a VHDL array of instance like we can do in Verilog arrays of instances?

Tags: vhdl

I have an entity which

```
entity adder is
  port (
    a, b : in  std_logic;
    sum  : out std_logic
  );
end entity adder;
architecture behav of adder is
begin
  sum <= a xor b;
end architecture behav;
```

How to create an array instantiation of this entity like we do in Verilog?  I tried to create a type of entity, it is showing It is not possible to create a entity type.

Comment: An instance represents the inclusion of external block specified by an entity or a configuration, it's not an object that be an element in array. Let's imagine your question as written so far is unclear. Can you explain what you intend?

Answer (score 1):

You will need multiple instances of the same entity, and vector signals to ease the coding. Let's begin from the first straightforward case with 3 entities:

```
#signals for entities
signal a0 : std_logic;
signal a1 : std_logic;
signal a2 : std_logic;

signal b0 : std_logic;
signal b1 : std_logic;
signal b2 : std_logic;

signal out0 : std_logic;
signal out1 : std_logic;
signal out2 : std_logic;

-- Entity instantiation

adder_0 : adder 
   port map(
        a => a0,
        b => b0,
        out => out0
  );


adder_1 : adder 
   port map(
        a => a1,
        b => b1,
        out => out1
  );


adder_2 : adder 
   port map(
        a => a2,
        b => b2,
        out => out2
  );
```

However this is not compact, there's a lot of repetition, and if the instances were 100 instead of 3 it would be almost impossible to write. Luckily VHDL has `for generate` loops and arrays:

```
-- Array type
type t_adder_array is array(2 downto 0) of std_logic;
signal a : t_adder_array;
signal b : t_adder_array;
signal out : t_adder_array;

-- or use a std_logic_vector because in your case the base type is just std_logic
-- please note that if the base type of the array is anything more complex, like a record, 
-- you need to define it with the array syntax.
signal a : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal b : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal out : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);

-- The we instantiate all the entities in a for loop

gen_adders: for k in 0 to 2 generate
   adder_k : adder 
      port map(
        a => a(k),
        b => b(k),
        out => out(k)
  );
end generate;
```

Comment: @user_1818839 is trying to correct you to say that is a `for generate` and not a `for loop`.